# Scripting Mavericks "Maps" app?

Tags: python, osx-mavericks, apple-maps

I had a small programming challenge extracting some data from various services using a small Python script. I wanted a quick and dirty way of visualizing this on a map, and since I worked on OSX I thought about the built-in Maps app.

However, I found no programmability whatsoever, except for its [very limited URL handling API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html).

Basically, I want to do this:

- Generate a list of coordinates with short text annotations
- Present the annotations on the map
- Make sure the zoom scale fits them all

I looked at various URL-based approaches, AppleScript, tried to look at command-line arguments or if you can load some types of files into Maps, but came up blank.

The best I could do was to show one annotation at a given coordinate, but I did not even manage to change its title.

Of course I know of MapKit, but the whole point is that I want to do this with almost no coding, preferrably from within my Python script (which of course could call AppleScripts etc).

Am I missing something fundamental here? It feels like this must obviously be possible. Or?